# Issue with AJAX + vb.net + asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Good morning I have an issue with a AJAX call to a vb.net server side function, my issue is that, never go to server code, I'm begin to be crazy :S

**scenario:**

Jquery Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notify() {
        alert($('#name').val());
        alert($('#phone').val());
        alert($('#email').val());
        alert($('#message').val());
        alert('{nombre: ' + $('#name').val() + ', telefono: ' + $('#phone').val() + ', dcorreo: ' + $('#email').val() + ', idea: ' + $('#message').val() + ' }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmail.aspx/sendnemail",
            data: '{nombre: ' + $('#name').val() + ', telefono: ' + $('#phone').val() + ', dcorreo: ' + $('#email').val() + ', idea: ' + $('#message').val() + ' }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
    </script>
```

I can see all alerts, and the values of field plugged here but, never go to server code

this is sendmail.aspx.vb:

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Partial Class sendmail
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function sendanemail(ByVal nombre As String, telefono As String, dcorreo As String, idea As String) As String
        Return "El mensjae ha sido enviado"
    End Function
End Class
```

sendmail.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="sendmail.aspx.vb" Inherits="sendmail" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: I move my code in senemail.aspx to Default.aspx and no work too

Comment: I suspect your problem lies in your typo: `url: "sendmail.aspx/sendnemail"` (there's a missing 'a'). Check how is called your server code function: `sendanemail`. Now you will get to the server side, but also keep the code suggested by @nikhil; it's the correct way to send data in your case.

Comment: yes, i change all, but no call received to the server, only make a postback and return to home

Comment: When you say no call received by the server, did you put a breakpoint in your server side function and it does not go in? Or do you simply not get an alert? Note that your ajax has `success: OnSuccess` and that function takes a parameter which is not provided. Perhaps the program goes to the server side but you do not get any alert message because of that?

Comment: yes i put a BreakPoint in to the server and no go to here, no show the success and fail function too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this declaring

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addanitem(idprod) {
        idprod = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var telefono = $("#phone").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "carthandler.aspx/SendEmail",
            data: '{name: "' + idprod + '", correo: "' + email + '", telefono: "' + telefono + '", idea: "' + message + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

Declaring, variables with the value in field